# SQLServer - Between two dates, generate table of Year, ISO Week, and Start and End dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to generate a table of Year, ISO Week Num, and Week Beginning/Ending dates, for all weeks between two dates.

This works, except when a Week 53 overflows into a new year.
In this case, 2020 Week 53 should span from 2020-12-28 to 2021-01-03.
Instead, because I'm grouping by ISO Week and Year, I get one record for 2020 Week 53 2020-12-28 to 2020-12-31, and then another erroneous record for 2021 Week 53 2021-01-01 to 2021-01-03.

```
DECLARE @windowStart DATE = '20200101',
        @windowEnd   DATE = '20211031';

;WITH report_dates AS (
        SELECT 
           TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @windowStart, @windowEnd) + 1)  
               report_date = DATEADD(DAY, 
                                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1,
                                     @windowStart) 
          FROM sys.all_objects AS a
    CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS b  
),
report_weeks AS (
    SELECT DATEPART(YEAR,     report_date) AS report_year,
           DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, report_date) AS report_week,
           MIN(report_date)                AS week_beginning_date,
           MAX(report_date)                AS week_ending_date
      FROM report_dates
  GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR,     report_date), 
           DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, report_date)
)
SELECT * FROM report_weeks ORDER BY week_beginning_date
```

[image]

I've also tried manually calculating the week_ending_date as week_beginning_date + 6 - but I still get an erroneous record for 2021 Week 53 beginning in January.  I could add one more filter to remove the extra record - maybe using a lag function to detect consecutive Week 53 records and remove the second one - but that seems like it's more complicated solution than necessary.  Is there an easier way to do this?

This is in SQLServer

Comment: Aside: Is a semicolon (`;`) a statement terminator or startinator?  You don't need both and might as well use it consistently and correctly as a terminator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, it's quite stupid to support ISO_WEEK, but no ISO_YEAR, only the combination YEAR/WEEK is usefull.

This modifies your existing query calculating the thursday of an ISO week, based on the definition of the ISO calendar each thursday is always in the correct year:

```
DECLARE @windowStart DATE = '20200101',
        @windowEnd   DATE = '20211031';

;WITH report_dates AS (
        SELECT 
           TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @windowStart, @windowEnd) + 1)  
               report_date = DATEADD(DAY, 
                                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1,
                                     @windowStart) 
          FROM sys.all_objects AS a
    CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS b  
),
report_weeks AS (
    SELECT DATEPART(YEAR,     D.thursday) AS report_year,
           DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, D.thursday) AS report_week,
           MIN(report_date)               AS week_beginning_date,
           MAX(report_date)               AS week_ending_date
    FROM report_dates 
                      -- get thursday of week
      CROSS APPLY(VALUES(CAST(DATEADD(DAY, (DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, report_date) / 7) * 7, 3) AS DATE))) AS D(thursday)
  GROUP BY D.thursday
)
SELECT * FROM report_weeks ORDER BY week_beginning_date
```

See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=129790a54fb7a3bdc5e7091c1284daf0)

Btw, this is a perfect use case for a calendar table. Instead of repeating the same calculations over and over again(the week of a date will never change), you do it once. You can add any date calculation you ever need as a new column and no user has to think about the correct algorithm.

Edit:

If you want to get full weeks you can do begin/end of week based on the thursday and then you don't need t other days of the week:

```
DECLARE @windowStart DATE = '20200101',
        @windowEnd   DATE = '20211031';

;WITH report_dates AS (
        SELECT 
           TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @windowStart, @windowEnd) + 1)  
               report_date = DATEADD(DAY, 
                                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1,
                                     @windowStart) 
          FROM sys.all_objects AS a
    CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS b  
),
report_weeks AS (
    SELECT DATEPART(YEAR,     report_date) AS report_year,
           DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, report_date) AS report_week,
           DATEADD(DAY, -3,   report_date) AS week_beginning_date,
           DATEADD(DAY,  3,   report_date) AS week_ending_date
    FROM report_dates 
    WHERE report_date = DATEADD(DAY, (DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, report_date) / 7) * 7, 3) 
)
SELECT * FROM report_weeks ORDER BY week_beginning_date
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c2b27be87711dcdede1b4b4b4fc61a8d)

This could be further simplified to get only one the thursday per week in the initial select :-)

```
DECLARE @windowStart DATE = '20200101',
        @windowEnd   DATE = '20211030';

;WITH report_dates AS (
        SELECT 
           TOP ((DATEDIFF(DAY, @windowStart, @windowEnd))/7 +1) 
               -- start on a thursday 
               report_date = DATEADD(WEEK, 
                                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1,
                                     DATEADD(DAY, (DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @windowStart) / 7) * 7, 3)) 
          FROM sys.all_objects AS a
    CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS b  
),
report_weeks AS (
    SELECT DATEPART(YEAR,     report_date) AS report_year,
           DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, report_date) AS report_week,
           DATEADD(DAY, -3,   report_date) AS week_beginning_date,
           DATEADD(DAY,  3,   report_date) AS week_ending_date
    FROM report_dates 
)
SELECT * FROM report_weeks ORDER BY week_beginning_date
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a123c545e3288bbcf45ac43d6beab918)

Comment: The edit is a work of art, that's brilliant - so you're selecting the window as Report Date +/- three days, and filtering for only thursdays - I swapped `WHERE report_date = DATEADD(DAY, (DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, report_date) / 7) * 7, 3)` with `WHERE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, report_date) = 5` and it looks like it produces matching results.  It's exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much!

Comment: Caution, results returned from DATEPART depend on SET DATEFIRST. Added another version creating only thursday :-)

Comment: That makes sense - my hesitation with using `DATEADD(DAY, (DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, report_date) / 7) * 7, 3) ` is I don't fully understand what it's doing.  It's taking the number of days between 0 (origin) and the report date, dividing that by 7, then multiplying that by 7 - then adding that number of days to (origin + 3 days), and comparing it to the report date?  I understand that ultimately it checks if a date is a thursday, but I don't understand why it works

Comment: `/ 7` truncates the difference, `* 7` returns a multiple of 7, i.e. full weeks. 1900-01-01 (date `0`) is a Monday -> date `3` is a Thursday. Now add full weeks to this adjusted start date and you get Thursdays only.

Comment: I understand now, & that's fantastic, thanks so much for your explanation.  I think either of your edits are perfect answers.  I don't have enough rep to upvote yet but I'll come back and do that when I can.  Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what your want:

```
DECLARE @windowStart DATE = '20200101',
        @windowEnd   DATE = '20211031';

with report_dates AS
(SELECT @windowStart AS report_date
UNION ALL
SELECT dateadd(wk, 1, report_date) as NextDate FROM report_dates WHERE report_date < @windowEnd)
SELECT DATEPART(YEAR,     report_date) AS report_year,
       DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, report_date) AS report_week,
       dateadd(dd, -datepart(weekday, report_date)+2, report_date) AS week_beginning_date,
       dateadd(dd, -datepart(weekday, report_date)+8, report_date) AS week_ending_date
FROM report_dates
```

In the datepart I apply +2 and +8 because my weeks begin on monday. If you have a different week starting day, please take a look at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

maybe...?

```
DECLARE @windowStart date = '20201220',
        @windowEnd date = '20210111';

;
WITH report_dates AS (SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @windowStart, @windowEnd) + 1)
                        report_date = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, @windowStart)
FROM sys.all_objects AS a
CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS b)

SELECT
  *,
  DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, report_date) AS report_week,
  CASE
    WHEN DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, report_date) > 50 AND MONTH(report_date) = 1 THEN YEAR(report_date) - 1
    WHEN DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, report_date) = 1 AND  MONTH(report_date) = 12 THEN YEAR(report_date) + 1
    ELSE YEAR(report_date)
  END AS report_year
FROM report_dates
```

Answer (score 0):

I accepted dnoeth's answer because it produces the right output right out of the box - I don't fully understand the 'cross-apply of thursdays', so I need to take some time to wrap my head around that

I did like GrahamH's check (if week > 50 and month = jan, something is wrong) - it seemed like the most straightforward.  Based on that, this is what I came up with - ultimately I'll either use this, or dnoeth's answer (provided I get to a point where I feel confident I understand it)

This also ensures the full week is included in the result set, in case your start/end dates cut a week off (I hadn't anticipated that being a problem)

```
DECLARE @windowStart DATE = '20100101',
        @windowEnd   DATE = '20211031';

;WITH date_list AS (
        SELECT 
           TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @windowStart, @windowEnd) + 8)  
               report_date = DATEADD(DAY, 
                                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1,
                                     DATEADD(DAY, -7, @windowStart)) 
          FROM sys.all_objects AS a
    CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS b  
),
report_weeks AS (
      SELECT CASE 
             WHEN DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, report_date) > 50
                  AND MONTH(report_date) = 1
             THEN YEAR(report_date) - 1
             WHEN DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, report_date) = 1
                  AND MONTH(report_date) = 12
             THEN YEAR(report_date) + 1
             ELSE YEAR(report_date) END      AS report_year,
             DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, report_date) AS report_week,
             report_date
        FROM date_list
),
min_max_dates AS (
     SELECT report_year,
            report_week,
            MIN(report_date) AS min_window,
            MAX(report_date) AS max_window
       FROM report_weeks
   GROUP BY report_year, 
            report_week
),
report_windows AS (
        SELECT report_year, 
               report_week, 
               min_window, 
               max_window
          FROM min_max_dates
         WHERE max_window >= @windowStart
           AND min_window <= @windowEnd
    )
SELECT * FROM report_windows ORDER BY min_window
```

Edit:

Final result from dnoeth's edited answer - I think this is fantastic, it's short & simple

```
DECLARE @windowStart DATE = '19500101',
        @windowEnd   DATE = '20211031';

;WITH report_dates AS (
        SELECT 
           TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @windowStart, @windowEnd) + 1)  
               report_date = DATEADD(DAY, 
                                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1,
                                     @windowStart) 
          FROM sys.all_objects AS a
    CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS b  
),
report_weeks AS (
    SELECT DATEPART(YEAR,     report_date) AS report_year,
           DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, report_date) AS report_week,
           DATEADD(DAY, -3, report_date)   AS week_beginning_date,
           DATEADD(DAY,  3, report_date)   AS week_ending_date
      FROM report_dates 
     WHERE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, report_date) = 5
)
SELECT * FROM report_weeks ORDER BY week_beginning_date
```

Last edit - dnoeth's two edited answers are preferable to this one, because they'll work regardless of your current `SET DATEFIRST` value

Comment: I use CROSS APPLY (instead of another CTE) to reuse the thursday calculation.